# How to go about verifiying if a prompt application prompting UAC?

Tags: windows-10

Every time the computer starts, UAC is prompted to verify a program. I don't really know how I should go about verifying if its trustworthy or not.

Image of the UAC prompt:

[image]

It shows the file path from .exe file from the local temp folder and link to see the certification.

I was thinking the easiest way to verify the application is to check the certification but don't know how to do that in certmgr.msc.

Comment: UAC isn't about "verifying" an application. It's about allowing (or denying) a request to run with administrator rights. You should instead investigate what's trying to install .NET 6 all the time.

Comment: You shouldn’t be able to take screenshots of the secure desktop have a feeling that prompt isn’t a UAC prompt, but I can’t tell, since it’s not in English

Comment: Worth pointing out that certificate already expire.

Comment: @Ramhound This is taken from another computer through Teamviewer.

Comment: Why are you trying to install .NET 6.0.20 when the current version is 6.0.26, if you ignore the fact, the actual current version is .NET 7.0.15

Comment: The installationen of the .NET 6.0.20 version is being prompted to be installed by a unknown reason. The common demoninator is that it shows everytime the computer is started. So its likely to be a program that autostart when the computer starts. My concern is if its safe to install due to looking odd. I was thinking the easiest way is to verify the certification but don't know how to do that in certmgr.msc.
Thanks in advanced for the help